# How to assign different values of variables to different instances of the same object?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties

I'm trying to set up a very basic system that creates a Levels object via its constructor:

```
class Levels
{
    // private level properties
    private static string levelName { get; set; }
    private static int levelSize { get; set; }
    private static int levelNum { get; set; }

    // new level constructor. Takes name, size (to square) and level number.
    public Levels(string inName, int inSize, int inNum)
    {
        levelName = inName;
        levelSize = inSize;
        levelNum = inNum;                       
    }

    // ... GetLevel methods here...
}
```

and assigns those values to each particular instance of the object. However the output indicates to me that the levelName, levelSize and levelNum variables aren't "sticking" to each instance properly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Level1 = new Levels("Forest", 15, 1);
        var Level2 = new Levels("Desert", 22, 2);

        Console.WriteLine($"--- {Level1.GetLevelName()}, level {Level1.GetLevelNum()} ---");
        Console.WriteLine($"--- {Level2.GetLevelName()}, level {Level2.GetLevelNum()} ---");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

// output:
//     --- Desert, level 2 ---
//     --- Desert, level 2 ---
// why is level 1 not displaying here?
```

I'm aware that if I were to move the constructor for level 2 after the first WriteLine command it would, hamfistedly, work, but obviously I need those values to stick to their instance.

Comment: You can't have instances of an object. Objects are instances *of classes* etc.

Comment: Whoops! Yep, you're right, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyword `static` means that the variable is not *instance* level, but *class* level.  Meaning your variables will be shared among all instances of your `Levels` class.

I would suggest rewriting it to:

```
public class Levels
{    
    public string LevelName { get; private set; }
    public int LevelSize { get; private set; }
    public int LevelNum { get; private set; }

    // new level constructor. Takes name, size (to square) and level number.
    public Levels(string inName, int inSize, int inNum)
    {
        LevelName = inName;
        LevelSize = inSize;
        LevelNum = inNum;                       
    }
}
```

Instead of your variables being `private static`, you will now use *Properties* that have a private setter (meaning they can only be set inside the class).  Now each of your *instances* of `Levels` has their own respective values and nothing is shared between instances. This will also give you the added bonus of eliminating the need for your `GetLevelName()`, `GetLevelNum()`, etc methods too.  You can now just say:

```
Console.WriteLine($"--- {Level1.LevelName}, level {Level1.LevelNum} ---");
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ESFwKI) to demo.

Comment: Looks like @maccettura beat me to the punch by a minute or so.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `static` keyword from fields. Basically `static` keyword means that this field is the same for all instances of this class.